# Variable static file names in Django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have many template files that have the following script at the end:

```
    {% block footer %}
        <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
```

At some point, I removed the file `'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'` and replaced it with the newer version `js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js`.

I don't want to update all of the template files manually to the new file name. Is there any shortcut that I can use? Something like:

```
    {% block footer %}
        <script src="{% static 'js/{{THE_LATEST_JS_FILE_NAME}}' %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
```

**Update:**

Current solution (based on the hint from @Pranav Totala):

In the `base.html` file I declare the variable:

```
    {% with THE_LATEST_JQUERY_FILE_PATH="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" %}
        {% block footer %}
        {% endblock %}
    {% endwith %}
```

In `child_001.html`:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    ...
    ...
    {% block footer %}
        <script src="{% static THE_LATEST_JQUERY_FILE_PATH' %}"></script>
        ...
        ...
    {% endblock %}
```

Any improvement on this is most welcome.

Comment: What's the point of having identical footer blocks in many child templates? Surely with template inheritance you just put the code in the parent?

Comment: The question might be ambiguous, not all templates need Jquery. And the content of the child footnotes generally different.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
{% extends index.html %}
{% extends base.html %}

{% block allscripts %}

THE_LATEST_JS_FILE_PATH='js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'
 <script src="{% static THE_LATEST_JS_FILE_PATH %}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

and in the base.html and index.html create blocks where you want to add these template

```
{% block allscripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Also no need of using `{{  }}` if you are already in `{%  %}` which makes it a python code**

Comment: Where is the best place to declare `THE_LATEST_JS_FILE_PATH='js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'`?

Comment: make a base.html where you have your code,  create a block `{% block allscripts %}  {% endblock %}` ,and make a new file where you write all this inside the same blocks.

Comment: Pl check the edit, and make a single base file and multiple blocks inside it

Comment: This doesn't work. You cannot declare variables in such a fashion in Django templates AFAIK.